# ajax - return only part of responsetext

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

The below is just a bit of my ajax code, at the moment my variable 'resp' is returning an entire response from test.php. Is there any way I can just return the responseText between a specified tag? ie. just get back the responseText of the html inside test.php's div of id="xyz"?

```
var loc="test.php?myinput=apple";
ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (ajax.readyState==4  && ajax.status == 200) {    
            var resp =  ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
ajax.open("GET",loc,true);
ajax.send(null);
```

Comment: You could use a library to parse the response HTML, and then find the DIV via a CSS selector. Like so: `$(resp).find('#xyz')`

Comment: If you are interested in the source text content of the DIV, I recommend a server-side script that would return it instead of searching for it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jquery shorthand function  load() to do this in a swift

```
$('#result').load('test.php' #container');
```

here result is the div where you want to place the response text and
container is the your specified source element location of test.php

is this what you want?

Answer (score 1):

change your ajax code to:

```
if (ajax.readyState==4  && ajax.status == 200) {    
   eval(ajax.responseText);
}
```

then in the test.php page, write for response like this

```
echo "document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML='abc';";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to switch to jQuery you could do the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.php?myinput=apple',
    method: 'POST',
    success : function( data ) {
        var content = $(data).find('#xyz').text();
        // alternativly the HTML
        // var content = $(data).find('#xyz').html();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to update some portion of your HTML with that response?
If so, you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and call the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) method that accepts a special `URL` parameter to load a portion of the returned HTML:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/P5KTv/